# How to filter particular column, which is delimited by quotation mark in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I need to filter particular column, which is delimited by quotation mark in CMD. Do you anybody know how to do it?

I know there is something like this

```
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("%VARIABLE%") do (
  echo %%a
  )
```

But in case if delimiter is quotation mark, this command it not usable...
For example here:

```
BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe" -c "C:\Program Files\Application\Application.conf" -f=false
```

I need to filter path for application exe file and path for application conf file...

Thank you in advance

mentioned in details

Comment: Using a quote as delimiter means, you can't enclose the options in quotes, which in turn means you have to escape some "poison chars" like spaces, commas `=`, quotes (and some others): `for /f tokens^=2^,4^ delims^=^" %%a in ("%variable%") do echo %%a    %%b` Looks awful, but works.

Answer (score 0):

For the task you've both implied and shown, I'm not really sure that you specifically need to filter using the doublequote as a delimiter. The reason I say that is that you're assuming that doublequotes will always exist in the string, which may not be the case if the files do not exist in locations using problem characters.

I would therefore advise that you instead filter using the two knowns, i.e. the file extensions.

Batch file example, (assumes your source data is the result of the `qc` option for `sc.exe`, *change `ServiceName` as needed*):

```bash
@For /F "Tokens=1,2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe qc ServiceName
 2^>NUL') Do @If "%%G" == "BINARY_PATH_NAME" For %%J In (%%I
) Do @If /I "%%~xJ" == ".exe" (Echo Application path is: %%~J
) Else If /I "%%~xJ" == ".conf" Echo Configuration file path is: %%~J
```

Or directly in cmd.exe:

```bash
For /F "Tokens=1,2,*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe qc ServiceName 2^>NUL') Do @If "%G" == "BINARY_PATH_NAME" For %J In (%I) Do @If /I "%~xJ" == ".exe" (Echo Application path is: %~J) Else If /I "%~xJ" == ".conf" Echo Configuration file path is: %~J
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your scant sample data,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "variable=BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe" -c "C:\Program Files\Application\Application.conf" -f=false"
SET "var1="
FOR %%e IN (%variable%) DO IF "%%e" neq "%%~e" IF DEFINED var1 (SET "var2=%%e") ELSE (SET "var1=%%e")
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

Simply processing `variable` as a list and detecting the quotes in the elements by comparing `%%e` and `%%~e`.